# How can I simplify my jQuery code to avoid repeating instructions?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Novice trying to simplify my jQuery, to avoid repetition**

I am a novice with Javascript and jQuery, but have written some code to display a tooltip on a form depending on the answer selected to a dropdown. Right now I am repeating the steps twice:

1. Once to check the dropdown on page load, in case it has reloaded due to a submission error - in this case, if an answer has been selected to that question, it will persist, and I need the tooltip to remain.
2. Once to check whenever the dropdown value changes.

The value of the dropdown is a number, so I've used that in the div classes to show the appropriate div. This is the code which is working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var service = "";
    var otherservice = "";

    // Check for select value on page load, in case it has refreshed due to a form error

    service = '.v' + $('select#989022_58716pi_989022_58716 option:selected').val();
    otherservice = '#form-tooltips div:not('+service+')';
    $('#form-tooltips div'+service).show();
    $(otherservice).hide();

    // Check again for select value, every time that selection changes

    $('select#989022_58716pi_989022_58716').on('change', function(){
        service = '.v' + $('select#989022_58716pi_989022_58716 option:selected').val();
        otherservice = '#form-tooltips div:not('+service+')';
        $('#form-tooltips div'+service).show();
        $(otherservice).hide();
    });
});

//The tooltips for display

$("<div id='form-tooltips'><div class='v1381962'>Tooltip 1</div><div class='v1381965'>Tooltip 2</div></div>").insertAfter(".add-tooltip-after");
```

What I would like to do is create a function - checkTooltip - so that I do not have to repeat those tooltip instructions the second time. I have tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var service = '';
    var otherservice = '';
    function checkTooltip({
        service = '.v' + $('select#989022_58716pi_989022_58716 option:selected').val();
        otherservice = '#form-tooltips div:not("+service+")';
        $('#form-tooltips div'+service).show();
        $(otherservice).hide();
    });
    checkTooltip();
    $('select#989022_58716pi_989022_58716').on('change', checkTooltip());
});
$("<div id='form-tooltips'><div class='v1381962'>Tooltip 1</div><div class='v1381965'>Tooltip 2</div></div>").insertAfter(".add-tooltip-after");
```

However this is not working. In the Chrome console, it says *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'* on the 5th line. I have tried removing that semicolon but then it gives me *Unexpected identifier 'otherservice'* instead.

Am I completely misunderstanding how this works or making some kind of syntax error? Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is definitely wrong, but in the function definition. It should look like this. No guarantees on whether the functionality is correct.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let service = '';
    let otherservice = '';
    const checkTooltip = () => {
        service = '.v' + $('select#989022_58716pi_989022_58716 option:selected').val();
        otherservice = '#form-tooltips div:not("+service+")';
        $('#form-tooltips div'+service).show();
        $(otherservice).hide();
    }
    checkTooltip();
    $('select#989022_58716pi_989022_58716').on('change', checkTooltip);
});
```

Note the change in the `on.change` handler at the end too.

Also its out of scope for your question but `989022_58716pi_989022_58716` probably could be rewritten with a more human-readable id or class.

Comment: Thank you for this! There was actually one other error I made above which was the quote marks around +service+, these managed to become double quotes somehow but I put them back to single quotes and now it works.

`otherservice = '#form-tooltips div:not('+service+')';`

Fully agree regarding `989022_58716pi_989022_58716` but this form is being generated by some software, and I'm not able to change it.